# PayPal Recurring Payments Error - Recurring payments profile description must be provided if the billing agreement type is recurring payments

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am having hard times implementing PayPal Recurring Payments with ExpressCheckout. Curl request is passing through just fine, however I keep getting the following error `Recurring payments profile description must be provided if the billing agreement type is recurring payments'`. I followed PayPal guide on setting curl options for that at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/ and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments

My curl options are set as follows (I will post only options referring the payment profile itself, as the curl request itself is fine):

```
'L_BILLINGTYPE0' => 'RecurringPayments',  
'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => 'Installment plan',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => 0,
'PROFILESTARTDATE0' => date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z")// UTC/GMT format

'DESC0' => 'Installment plan',
'BILLINGPERIOD0' => 'Month',
'BILLINGFREQUENCY0' => 1,
'AMT0' => 250.00,
'CURRENCYCODE0' => 'CAD',
'TOTALBILLINGCYCLES0' => 4
```

According to documentation when you just set the API Call (doing API operation `SetExpressCheckout`) you don't need to provide all the details, just `L_BILLINGTYPE0` and `L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0`, but the result was the same - `Recurring payments profile description must be provided if the billing agreement type is recurring payments'`

So, I tried setting all possible options and again failed. I hope someone has already had experience with PayPal recurring payments and can help me out, seriously, PayPal documentation is just horrible! What I am missing?

EDIT: FIXED

Oops, that was my bad (typo in variable).

Correct procedure:

1. Make SetExpressCheckout API call with required options: `L_BILLINGTYPE0` and `L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0`
2. Grab PayPal token.
3. Do GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call (optional) if you want to grab details of a payment and payer.
4. Do DoExpressCheckout API call (required) to complete the transaction where you will need to specify other recurring payments profile details.

Comment: Go there and check your proper parameters. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/